# i want my falling sprites to dissapear half way down the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

im new to programming, i have been experimenting with cocos2d, heres the problem, i have made a simple game, device in portrait, it has falling sprites, and i want the sprite to disappear when the position of the top of the sprite < screen.height/2 how can this be done?

heres some code you may be interested in:

this is the falling sprite, it falls from the top of the screen to the bottom

```
-(void)addRock {

CCSprite *rock = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rock.png" 
                                     rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)]; 

// Determine where to spawn the target along the X axis
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int minX = rock.contentSize.width/2;
int maxX = winSize.width - rock.contentSize.width/2;
int rangeX = maxX - minX;
int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

// Create the target slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the X axis as calculated above
rock.position = ccp(actualX, 500);
[self addChild:rock];

// Determine speed of the target
int actualDuration = spriteDuration;//speed of sprite

// Create the actions
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(actualX,-winSize.height+ rock.contentSize.height)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[rock runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, nil]];
```

}

when the sprite move has finished

```
-(void)spriteMoveFinished:(id)sender {
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)sender;
[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
```

}

Comment: i believe your spriteMoveFinished is not getting invoked?

Comment: not yet, how do i get it to fit in with the sprite code?

Comment: ok, just added: id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];

Comment: so when actually your spriteMoveFinished is getting invoked now?

Comment: yep its invoked, i have added it to my code above.

Comment: all you need to fade out and call remove now. refer to @Tharabas for fading ur sprite then on the callback you can run removeChild code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fade your sprite out halfway of the Animation you can use CCSpawn to combine the *falling* animation with the *fadeOut*. But as you want it to fade out after a given time, you need to create a Sequence of `CCDelayTime` and `CCFadeOut`.

```
double fadeStart = 0.5;
id wait    = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: actualDuration * fadeStart];
id fadeOut = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration: actualDuration * (1.0 - fadeStart)];
id waitThenFade = [CCSequence actions: wait, fadeOut, nil];

id actionMove = ...;
id fullAnimation = [CCSpawn actions:actionMove, waitThenFade, nil];

[rock runAction:[CCSequence actions:fullAnimation, actionMoveDone, nil]];
```

In case you want the fading to start earlier or later you simply have to move the fadeStart value. 0 will start immediately, 1 will actually not fade, so better pick a value in between.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, line 3 of your code, is there a * after actualDuration?

Comment: also i have edited your last line to: [rock runAction:[CCSpawn actions:actionMove,waitThenFade,actionMoveDone, nil]];

Comment: I must have forgotten the `actionMoveDone` as you did not put that in your original post either ;) But you'll have to wrap that in a Sequence, as you probably want the moveDone to be triggered after the last event.

Comment: aah i still cant get it to fade! i cant see where the problem is!

Comment: i have the same as above but with: `id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(actualX,-winSize.height+rock.contentSize.height)];` and `id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];`

Comment: and i have put it all at the bottom of the addRock method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

CCSprite* img = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"yourSprite.png"];
img.position = ccp(size.width/2,size.height + img.boundingBox.size.height/2);
[img runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                    [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(img.position.x,size.height/2 - img.boundingBox.size.height/2)],
                    [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1],
                    [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:nil selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],
                    nil]];
```

Comment: how do i make the move to half the screen? i tried that but im not sure if i done it right